# Cerrar form dentro de panel

Tags: c#, visual-studio

que tal disculpen tengo un problema al tratar de cerrar un form dentro de un panel, lo que pasa es que me arroja un error en el momento de cerrar dicho formulario anexo el codigo para su analisis .
tengo un formulario principal dentro de el tengo un panel y en ese panel voy abriendo firmularios respectivamente . al cerrar alguno de estos formularios dentro del panel tiene que quedar abierto el formulario principal.
es decir, en el formPrincipal esta un panel, en el cual se iran abriendo forms dentro de este panel(del principal)

codigo de cerrar formulaio dentro del panel

```
    public void RemoveFormInPanel(Form formHijo)
    {

        formHijo.TopLevel = false;
        formHijo.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
        formHijo.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        plMenuMain.Controls.Remove(formHijo);
        this.Tag = formHijo;
        formHijo.Close();
    }
```

codigo de la clase programa

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        frmPrincipal main = new frmPrincipal();
        main.Show();
        Application.Run();// aqui me marca el error
    }
```

Comment: Puedes probar lo siguiente: elimina la línea `main.Show()` y cambia `Application.Run()` por `Application.Run(main)`.

Comment: lo he realizado pero sigue igual. y me arroja esto todavia  "Información adicional: Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto."

Comment: Porque cambiaste la forma del main? Application.Run tiene que ir antes de mostrar el form.